# selenium RC (python) having trouble with nested iframes

Tags: jquery, python, xml, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to navigate selenium in python to send text to an input field on the Indeed website example test page (click apply to see the form with input fields name, phone, email, cover letter ,etc)

http://www.indeed.ca/cmp/HD-GROUP/jobs/Regional-Representative-a72711272aba6984?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk40tHzG2V8PFLUkYNu3gUARzMPxmzfYNIZhnUOBL3fqJ0waO2mcYR2CrxwZY5aM-JSDuEjnVcDU8mqRWS8wbyaI

I realize I need to tell selenium to switch into that iframe the problem is there's actually two.

I have the following XML paths:

```
//*[@id="indeed-ia-1444850868596-1-modal-iframe"] <-- first iframe

/html/body/iframe <-- second iframe

//*[@id="apply_form"]  <-- form
```

inputs:

```
//*[@id="form_container"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]
//*[@id="form_container"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div
//*[@id="phone_container"]
//*[@id="form_container"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]
```

how do I put these things together?

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to click "Apply Now" button, wait for the `iframe` to become present, then switch to it, then switch to an inner `iframe`, locate the input boxes and send keys. Working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.indeed.ca/cmp/HD-GROUP/jobs/Regional-Representative-a72711272aba6984?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk40tHzG2V8PFLUkYNu3gUARzMPxmzfYNIZhnUOBL3fqJ0waO2mcYR2CrxwZY5aM-JSDuEjnVcDU8mqRWS8wbyaI")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.indeed-apply-button").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

driver.find_element_by_id("applicant.name").send_keys("test")
```